# GAE: Creating a a child entity automatically

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

In the GAE application I am developing, I have a `Room` entity, which has a `KeyProperty` to a `Match` object. The room should always have a match, and that match can't exist without the room.

Now, I am assuming that I have to create a match object like this:

```
Match(parent=room.key)
```

But, the room always requires a match to be created, and the only way I can think of doing this is as follows:

```
room = Room()
match = Match(parent=room.put())
room.match_key = match.put()
room.put() # again!
```

Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Comment: your first put pushes room to the datastore and returns the key.  I don't see why you need a second put at all.  Put is update AND insert, so the code will work without your last line.

a 1-1 relationship isn't handled as it is in relational databases, you may need to rethink your model differently.

If I understood well you're trying to have Match.put done at the same time you have Room.put?

Comment: @Julldar Sorry, I missed a line in the code. The put is now required, I think. Can you please on the 1-1 relationship? A room can exist if the match goes away, I just create another match. This design looks sane to me?

Comment: With that line of code, yeah a put would be needed.  What you can do if you want though is to manually assign the key (you just need to make sure it's always a different key).  If you want to use relationships, you might be better off using CloudSQL instead of the datastore?

Comment: @Julldar Thanks, I'll check CloudSQL (even though I like the NoSQL simplicity). Another possibility I overlooked is `LocalStructuredProperty`. I have to work on minor model design changes, but I think it'll work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why you want both the Match to have the Room as a parent, and the parent to have a KeyProperty to the Match. This is unnecessarily circular. Choose one or the other: if you want a parent/child relationship, keep the parent key and query the Match via `ancestor()`; otherwise leave out the parent key, so no need to create the Room first.